# Laravel - Refactoring User Permission "Gate::Define" Code Into Easier to Read Code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

So what i'm basically trying to do is refactor my long bit of code to something more simpler. I found this snippet of code at this [website](https://thewebtier.com/laravel/understanding-roles-permissions-laravel/) and I don't really understand what's going on inside the code. I don't think that this snippet of code will work considering I am using different policies and methods then what's standard.

**Code Snippet From Site:**

```
//PermissionsServiceProvider.php 
public function boot()
 {
     Permission::get()->map(function($permission){
        Gate::define($permission->slug, function($user) use ($permission){
           return $user->hasPermissionTo($permission);
        });
     });
 }
```

Can someone please explain what exactly is going on in this bit of code?

My Code:

```
// Posts Policy
Gate::define('post.view', 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@view');
Gate::define('post.create', 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@create');
Gate::define('post.update', 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@update');
Gate::define('post.delete', 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@delete');
Gate::define('post.publish', 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@publish');
Gate::define('post.edit', 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@edit');
Gate::define('post.global', 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@global');

// Categories Policy
Gate::define('category.view', 'App\Policies\Blog\CategoriesPolicy@view');
Gate::define('category.create', 'App\Policies\Blog\CategoriesPolicy@create');
Gate::define('category.update', 'App\Policies\Blog\CategoriesPolicy@update');
Gate::define('category.delete', 'App\Policies\Blog\CategoriesPolicy@delete');
Gate::define('category.edit', 'App\Policies\Blog\CategoriesPolicy@edit');
Gate::define('category.global', 'App\Policies\Blog\CategoriesPolicy@global');

// Tags Policy
Gate::define('tag.view', 'App\Policies\Blog\TagsPolicy@view');
Gate::define('tag.create', 'App\Policies\Blog\TagsPolicy@create');
Gate::define('tag.update', 'App\Policies\Blog\TagsPolicy@update');
Gate::define('tag.delete', 'App\Policies\Blog\TagsPolicy@delete');
Gate::define('tag.edit', 'App\Policies\Blog\TagsPolicy@edit');
Gate::define('tag.global', 'App\Policies\Blog\TagsPolicy@global');

// Parts Section Policy
Gate::define('part.section.view', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartSectionsPolicy@view');
Gate::define('part.section.create', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartSectionsPolicy@create');
Gate::define('part.section.update', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartSectionsPolicy@update');
Gate::define('part.section.delete', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartSectionsPolicy@delete');
Gate::define('part.section.edit', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartSectionsPolicy@edit');
Gate::define('part.section.global', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartSectionsPolicy@global');

// Parts Policy
Gate::define('part.view', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartsPolicy@view');
Gate::define('part.create', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartsPolicy@create');
Gate::define('part.update', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartsPolicy@update');
Gate::define('part.delete', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartsPolicy@delete');
Gate::define('part.edit', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartsPolicy@edit');
Gate::define('part.global', 'App\Policies\Parts\PartsPolicy@global');

// Admin Management Policy
Gate::define('admin.global', 'App\Policies\AdminManagementPolicy@global');

// User Management Policy
Gate::define('user.global', 'App\Policies\UserManagementPolicy@global');
```

Is there a way to do this as a foreach loop from my permissions table? Here's some Pseudo code:

```
foreach($permissions as $permission) {
    Gate::define($permission->slug, 'App\Policies\' . $permission->category . 'Policy@' . $permission->name);
}
```

**Question:** Any way to make my code more compact and easier to read like the code snippet from the website?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the author of that article did not use policies at all, he created a permissions table and then bound the permissions he created to laravel gates by the code snippet

```
 Permission::get()->map(function($permission){
    Gate::define($permission->slug, function($user) use ($permission){
       return $user->hasPermissionTo($permission);
    });
 });
```

Let's break it line by line

```
Permission::get() // Query all permissions defined in permissions database table
->map(function($permission){ // Foreach permission do the following
   Gate::define($permission->slug, // Create new gate with the permission slug
   function($user) use ($permission){
      return $user->hasPermissionTo($permission); // the user table has many to many relation with permissions table, here we only check if $user is associated with $permission
   });
});
```

To make your code more dynamic, I suggest you to do the following:

### Database structure

1. Create `permission` database table
2. Create `roles` database table
3. Create `permission_role` pivot database table
4. Create `role_user` pivot database table

### Define Relationships

1. Role has many permissions ( many to many relationship, define it with `belongsToMany` )
2. Permission belongs to many roles ( many to many relationship, define it with `belongsToMany` )
3. User has many roles ( many to many relationship, define it with `belongsToMany` )

### Reduce the number of `global` permissions

By utilising `Gate::before` you can allow specific user who has `global` or `root` permission to authorise all defined abilities:

```
Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
    if ($user->hasPermission('root-access')) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

If you implement the database permissions you no longer need to create policies for every model, and the gates will be defined using the above code dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, your existing code is fine. It works. It is readable. While it might become more verbose as your app grows, it also might not. So why improve it?

That said, here are some ideas. Most of your code is a mapping between permission and policy implementation. For example `'part.view'` maps to `'App\Policies\Parts\PartsPolicy@view`. The "weight" of this mapping can't be removed: it can only be moved.

You might consider moving it to a simpler configuration file, something that looks like this:

```
// config/permission-map.php
<?php return [
    'post.view' => 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@view',
    'post.create' => 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@create',
    'post.update' => 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@update',
    'post.delete' => 'App\Policies\Blog\PostsPolicy@delete',
    // etc...
];
```

Then in your boot you read that config and iterate:

```
// boot permissions
$permission_map = require_once('config/permission_map.php');
foreach ($permission_map as $permission => $policy_implementation) {
    Gate::define($permission, $policy_implementation);
}
```

Advantage: adding a new policy mapping only changes the most salient information, and you don't have to think about how to make that mapping happen - today that is `Gate::define` but tomorrow maybe it's `Sentry::policy`. Additionally, by separating data from the code, you can test the code more freely.

Another approach could be annotations: in the DocBlock of your policy implementation, you write your own annotation syntax, which you then parse and compile into the configuration file. Along the lines of

```
namespace App\Policies\Blog;

class PostsPolicy {
    /**
     * @permission post.view
     */
    public function view() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I, personally, am not a fan of this: it adds a layer of inner framework whose value I find it hard to measure.